# Why is PHPUnit still failing on SQL error, even though I have caught the exception

Tags: php, database, phpunit

I am trying to build a wrapper class that simplifies SQL access within my application (amongst other things). When testing my class with PHPUnit, a SQL error kills the test and spits out the error message to the console despite the fact that I have caught and handled the exception.

I have tried using a @expectedexception. This works, except I now can't do any more assertions; I want to test that the method returns the error as an array.

Any help much appreciated.

```
$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare query and respond to errors. If there is errors, stop processing any more queries
try {
    $PDOQuery = $db->prepare($query['query']);
}
catch ( PDOException $error )
{
    $error = $error->errorInfo;
    $this->parent->errors[] = array( 'type' => 'Database error (Prepare)',
        'details' => 'The MySQL server returned an error. Check your DB logs for more details' );

    error_log( "SQL Prepare Error code (SQLSTATE): $error[0]");
    error_log( "SQL Prepare Error code (Vendor): $error[1]");
    error_log( "SQL Prepare Error message: $error[2]");
    break;
}


try {
    // Execute query and respond to errors. If there is errors, stop processing any more queries
    $result = $PDOQuery->execute(isset ($query['params']) ? $query['params'] : array());
}

catch ( PDOException $error ) {
    $error = $error->errorInfo();

    $logsMessage = "Check your server logs for more information.";

    switch($error[1])
    {
        case 1452: $message = "MySQL failed to add a row. Possibly you missed out some mandatory fields? $logsMessage"; break;
        default: $message = "MySQL Returned an error (Execute). $logsMessage"; break;
    }

    $this->parent->errors[] = array( 'type' => 'Database error',
        'details' => $message );

    error_log( "SQL Execute Error code (SQLSTATE): $error[0]");
    error_log( "SQL Execute Error code (Vendor): $error[1]");
    error_log( "SQL Execute Error message: $error[2]");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I worked out what the problem was.

I had my code within a namespace, and I had forgotten to reference the global namespace in the catch statement.

So I changed it to

`catch ( \PDOException $error )`

And my problem resolved itself.